# Пагинация WordPress

Tags: wordpress, site

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли создать пагинацию по произвольным полям?
То есть допустим на странице есть 196 произвольных полей и сделать так, чтобы страницы были отсортированы по произвольным полям( на каждой странице должно быть по 25 произвольных полей). Можно ли так сделать?

Comment: поля внутри повторителя?

Comment: Всё можно. Читайте про pre_get_posts